# clojure web development - looking for a payment gateway/ processing library

Tags: clojure, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am new to [clojure](http://clojure.org/) and I am planning to develop a small webshop using clojure and one of those clojure web frameworks (Compojure, Noir, Ring, etc).

My question is, when it comes to processing customer's payment, for example processing credit card, debit card, etc, is there any existing clojure payment process library, like [Active Merchant](http://activemerchant.org/) for Rails, that I can use?

Otherwise, I will write my own based on the API/requirements from the payment company I choose to integrate, but still I don't want to reinvent the wheels.

Comment: I don't think there is such a library but wrapping a nicely designed REST API from a payment gateway wont be much of an issue, specially in a language like clojure.

Comment: It would be worth exploring Java-based solutions as well - it's very easy to use a Java library directly from Clojure so this is often the simplest approach

Comment: Here is a webshop project in Clojure, with Stripe integrated as payment system. It also has a client app: https://github.com/i-schuetz/clojushop

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [clj-stripe](http://clojars.org/abengoa/clj-stripe). [Here](https://github.com/abengoa/clj-stripe)'s the GitHub repository.

Comment: Here is a webshop implementation in Clojure that uses Stripe as payment system (it also has a client app): https://github.com/i-schuetz/clojushop